# Using Gradle flavors on vlc-android-sdk

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, vlc-android

In my app I'm using `"de.mrmaffen:vlc-android-sdk:2.0.6"` library and it's taking much storage but I can't find a smaller alternative.
So I decided as [CommonsWare mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45121198/7592874) to use splits or product flavors but I can't get it to work.
I tried to follow the docs with no luck.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: This is a pretty low-effort question. What have you tried? What do you mean you can't get it to work?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question "I tried to follow the docs with no luck."

Comment: Where are your examples of following the docs? In what way is it not working for you? You have not provided enough information for someone to assist you. If you don't add these details, you're not very likely to find the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Building the LibVLC Android SDK yourself**

If you are using `"de.mrmaffen:vlc-android-sdk:2.0.6"`, [buid the LibVLC Android SDK yourself](https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile)

> As explained [here](https://github.com/mrmaffen/vlc-android-sdk/commit/769f36551957efb20aa0f5b89c041a678766595b?short_path=04c6e90#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8), afterwards simply run this Gradle command: `./gradlew buildLibVlc`

---

### **Building a specific version of the LibVLC Android SDK**

```
cd vlc-android          // if this folder doesn't exist yet, simply run ./gradlew cloneVlcAndroid
git tag                 // to list all release versions
git checkout {tag-name} // to checkout the git repo at the given tag
cd ..
./gradlew buildLibVlc   // build it
```

Make sure you followed the Android compile instructions in terms of dependencies and check [this](https://github.com/mrmaffen/vlc-android-sdk/issues/63#issuecomment-289772640):

> 1. `git clone` repo.
> 2. open up a command prompt in this repo. "cd" or change directory into
>      it.
> 3. `git clone .`
> 4. change directory into the vlc-android directory.
> 5. `git tag`
> 6. `git checkout <tag_version>`. In this case, 2.1.2.
> 7. `cd ..`
> 8. comment out both the `compile/build` of the `build.gradle` script that
>      you don't need.
> 9. `./gradlew buildLibVlc`
> 10. you should have a successful build with both the Java sources and
>        shared object (*.so) files in the `jniLibs` folder.
> 11. create a `libs` folder right next to the `jniLibs` folder if you
>        updated the gradle version.

---

### **Get it via Maven CentralJCenter**

> Just add this dependency to your project and you're good to go.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'de.mrmaffen:libvlc-android:2.1.12@aar'
}
```

I'm using this version. Remember to add JCenter to your project's `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

VLC Android SDK via JCenter supports the next ABIs: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86 and x86_64.

You can filter specific ABIs in your app's `build.gradle` file (x86_64 and arm64-v8a are excluded):

```
android {
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
```

It's possible to check included files in [mrmaffen's repository](https://github.com/mrmaffen/vlc-android-sdk/tree/master/libvlc-android/src/main/jniLibs) and via recent Android Studio versions:

[image]

---

### **Configure multiple APKs for ABIs**

> Add an abi block inside
>   your [splits](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.Splits.html) block. In your abi block, provide a [list of desired](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa) ABIs. [Source](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html#configure-abi-split)

```
android {
  ...
  splits {

    // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
    abi {

      // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
      enable true

      // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
      // want APKs for x86 and armeabi-v7a.

      // Resets the list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for to none.
      reset()

      // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
      include "x86", "armeabi-v7a"

      // Specifies that we do not want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
      universalApk false
    }
  }
}
```

---

### **Build multiple APKs**

> Click **Build > Build APK** to build all APKs for the currently selected
>   module in the Project pane.
>
> Gradle creates the APKs for each ABI
>   into the project's `build/outputs/apk/` directory.

---

### **Configure Build Variants**

[This page](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) builds on the [Configure Your Build Overview](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html) to show you how you can configure build variants to create different versions of your app.

---

### **Combine abi filters and build variants**

[Exclude abi from apk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32334063/1009132)

> ```
> android {
>     productFlavors {
>         x86 {
>             ndk {
>                 abiFilter "x86"
>             }
>         }
>         arm {
>             ndk {
>                 abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

---

### **Multi-APK through ABI and density splits**

[How to reduce the number of APKs with ABI splits](https://medium.com/@wkalicinski/smallerapk-part-4-multi-apk-through-abi-and-density-splits-477083989006)

> [Here](https://medium.com/@wkalicinski/smallerapk-part-4-multi-apk-through-abi-and-density-splits-477083989006)’s
>   a code snippet that you can use to set version codes for ABI splits.
>
> Give the x86_64 and x86 higher version numbers than ARM, as many x86
>   devices can run ARM code through an emulation layer, although with
>   lower performance.
>
> If you don’t wish to manage too many APKs, target the most popular
>   ones (usually ARM and maybe x86) with a split APK and serve a
>   universal APK to everyone else.
>
> It’s vital that you publish the universal APK on the Play Store with a lower
>   version number than all other ABI-specific packages.
>
> If you need more flexibility for your Multi-APK setup, check out
>   [Multi-APK through product
>   flavors.](https://medium.com/@wkalicinski/smallerapk-part-5-multi-apk-through-product-flavors-e069759f19cd)

---

### **Recommended Medium post to choose supported ABIs**

> [In this
>   post](https://android.jlelse.eu/controlling-apk-size-when-using-native-libraries-45c6c0e5b70a)
>   we will understand what is ABI, problems with the ABI split, and
>   alternative way to avoid those problems... For instance, Android supports the following ABIs :
>
> ```
> mips, mips64, X86, X86–64, arm64-v8a, armeabi, armeabi-v7a
> ```

[image]

> So you have to take a call on supporting 64-bit libraries based on
>   size vs performance criteria but mips, mips-64, and armeabi should be
>   removed without any hesitation.

---

### **Solve UnsatisfiedLinkError Problem on some devices**

[As explained here](https://medium.com/mobiwise-blog/unsatisfiedlinkerror-problem-on-some-android-devices-b77f2f83837d), 64-bit processors generate and check arm64 folder to load native libraries.

If your project does not have arm64 folder. Here is the solution:

**build.gradle**

```
defaultConfig {
    ...

    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }

}
```

> You need to add this filters(abiFilters) to your app module’s
>   build.gradle files. So when your device try to run your app, it will
>   check gradle file and understands that it should not generate any
>   folder and use existing native library resources. Boom. Almost solved.
>   But still there is one more thing. Add this line to your gradle.properties to use deprecated Ndk.

**gradle.properties**

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use app bundle so you don't need to handle multiple apks. Google Play will handle it for you automatically. Plus this approach can provide additional benefits. For more details: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle